# Computing the False Positive Rate (FPR) and True Positive Rate (TPR) in a CNN

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am designing a CNN for classification two types of images, and I need to compute the FPR and TPR.

In the following, you can see my code, but I don't know how can I compute FPR and TPR based on this code.
Could you please let me know how can I do that. 
I know for computing the FPR and TPR I can use the following code

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_predic)
```

while y_predict can be computed by `y_predic = model.predict(x_test)`

but in my code, I don't know how can do that.
I would be so thankful if you could help me.

```
num_classes = 1
batch_size = 512
epoch = 100

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='Valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='Same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='Same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))

model.add(Flatten())


model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(units=num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:/Data/CNN/train',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = batch_size,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:/Data/CNN/test',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode = 'binary', shuffle= True)


history = model.fit_generator(training_set,
                             steps_per_epoch = 4000//batch_size,
                             epochs = epoch,
                             verbose= 2,
                             validation_data = test_set,
                             validation_steps = 1000//batch_size)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'compute'? Do you need FPR and TPR to be outputted alongside `metrics=['accuracy']` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need just FPR and TPR to calculate sensitivity and specificity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `keras.metrics` almost as is. It has both FPR, TPR and `SensitivityAtSpecificity`

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity(0.5)])
```

But keras model supports only `keras.metrics`, so no `tf.metrics` could be used without writing custom metric

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to use it, but I don't know how can I import this part in my code. Because the SensitivityAtSpecificity does not defined in tf.keras.metrics

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf` or you can use `keras.metrics` depending on your inputs

Comment: I did it before. But  SensitivityAtSpecificity does not define in tf.keras.metrics

Comment: Glad to hear. If the answer was helpful, please consider upvote/accept

Comment: No sorry, I deleted my message. Because for having the SensitivityAtSpecificity in my tf.keras.metrics I have to replace my metrics.py with the code mentioned in your link. But unfortunately, after that, I cannot import my keras.

Comment: Are you able to import tensorflow?

Comment: Finally, the problem solved. I have upgraded my pycharm packages and the problem solved. Before that the the SensitivityAtSpecificity was not defined in tf.keras.metrics.

Comment: But now I have a new error.   `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Resource localhost/true_positives/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
  [[{{node metrics/sensitivity_at_specificity/AssignAddVariableOp}}]]
  [[{{node metrics/sensitivity_at_specificity/Mean}}]]`

Comment: Please ask another question with full error traceback and code